# Populating a combobox with a query from my dataset

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

i want to fill a combobox using a query I added in the dataset?  the query should give an output depending on a previous combobox selection.any help on how I can code it

this is my code so far but it doesn't want to work

---

Ok so I updated my code but now it gives me the whole tables inputs, but I want it to be filtered by what ever option I choose in the cmbSchool. How do I filter it now using the parameter?

here is my new code

```
 private void cmbSchool_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int ischoolid = Convert.ToInt16(cmbSchool.SelectedValue);

        try
        {
            cmbClassRoomName.DataSource = this.geared4MathDataSet.ClassRoom;
            cmbClassRoomName.ValueMember = "ClassRoomID";
            cmbClassRoomName.DisplayMember = "ClassRoomName";
            //this.classRoomTableAdapter.FillBySchool(this.geared4MathDataSet.ClassRoom, ischoolid);
            lblClassroomName.Visible = true;
            cmbClassRoomName.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: _doesn't want to work_ really is not much descriptive. You have a try catch, what is the error message? Or if no message what doesn't work?

Comment: error message is : Cannot bind to new value member. Parameter name: Value

Comment: ValueMember and DisplayMember should be the name of a field present in the DataSource. What is the value returned by your Convert.ToString(.....). If it is not the name of a field that's explain the error. Use a temporary string variable to receive the result of your Convert.ToString() and using the debugger check the value returned. (By the way, your need to convert this to a string is a dead give-away that something is not really a field name)

Comment: alright thanks :) will go check now :)

Comment: check for _filter_ property in your dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter your `ClassRoom` typed datatable to return just the record with the `schoolid` selected you could write

```
cmbClassRoomName.DataSource = this.geared4MathDataSet.ClassRoom
                              .Where(x => x.IDSchool == ischoolid)
                              .CopyToDataTable();
```

This, of course, assumes that you have a field named IDSchool in the ClassRoom table. You could adjust the name used here to the correct one